# SLF4J logging interface with JDK Logger

Tags: java, slf4j, java.util.logging

I using slf4j logging interface with JDK logger for my web service project. I have been actually using Java util logging and currently thinking of move to using slf4j with JDK logger. 
I have included slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12 jar file dependency in my ivy.xml file

In one of my classes, I have the following:

```
  import org.slf4j.Logger;
  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 public class Example{
   public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class);

   public void sampleMethod() {

     logger.info("Logging this method");
}
}
```

After running this class/method, I dont see any log output to either the console or to any log file. Currently the java util logging framework under use, write the logs to a file. I looked in that folder to check to see if any log files related to this class was created, but none.

Can you please help me to identify why this is not working. I read online about configuring the logging.properties. I am not sure how to do that, where to place the properties file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you are looking to migrate to `SLF4j` with `java.util.logging` as an implementation. For that you'll need to provide SLF4j bridge jars for `log4j` and `jcl` over `SLF4j` which most likely is the reason why you don't see any output.

In other words according to this [very nice descriptive depiction](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) you'll need to follow this approach:

[image]